# Multiple Instances of @Configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a `@configuration` (MyConfig) class which creates a few beans. This works fine.

But now I have a requirement to create multiple instances of this configuration (MyConfig) based on a List

Something like

```
list.foreach(new MyConfig(myBean4))  // but this is not correct obviously
```

So that I am able to use corresponding myBean4 inside each instance of MyConfig

How can this be achieved ?

```
@Configuration 
public class MyConfig {

  @Autowired
  CustomBean1 mybean1;

  public MyConfig() {
  }


  @Bean
  public CustomBean2 getBean2(@Qualifier("myChannel"){ ...}

  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
  public void myReciever(@Header("abc") SomeBean bean ){...}

  @Bean
  public CustomBean3 myChannel(){...}

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry if this was not obvious, added the question on main thread. Basically want to know how can this be achieved ?